# Does SFTP ask for a prompt input when first connecting to an SFTP server?

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sftp

I have a script that connects to a SFTP server and downloads some files. On my local machine, it runs perfectly fine.

However, I need to run this on AWS' infrastructure and have tried running the commands in a shell script executed by an EC2 instance. The EC2 instance is not persistent; it is spun up every time I run a data pipeline.

So my question is this: since a new machine runs the shell script every single time, does it get prompted by SFTP (or is it Bash?) for authentication and verifying that I want to use the key? When I was testing the script on my local machine, there were a few times when my Cygwin shell prompted me with something along the lines of "Do you want to use this key?".

If there's a prompt for that, how do I avoid it, or make sure the key is stable and usable for the SFTP connection?

The error I'm getting on the AWS EC2 instance is:

```
Host key verification failed.
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 2):

If the host key isn't present in your `known_hosts` file, or the key doesn't match what's there, SSH-based applications will normally prompt you to accept it. You can disable this by putting

```
StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

in your ~/.ssh/config file.

Comment: Is this the right command to make that change from a bash script: `ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no $h uptime`?

Comment: Yes, you can put options on the command line like that.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you connect to a host, the host key won't be present in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` so ssh will prompt you to accept it or reject it. You should configure the machine to start with this value already present in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before
And this is how i solved it.

1. Create a new instance
2. Create a new volume
3. mount the volume
4. Copy these files to the new volume

   - /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
   - /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
   - /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
   - /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
   - /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
   - /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub

Now you need to configure that your new instance will mount the new volume and copy the files back

you need to put the the commands in you user data 
so everytime you start the instance, it will

1. update the repository (sudo apt-get update)
2. install aws cli
3. mount the volume that contains your keys
4. copy the keys ( i use cat, to preserve permissions and ownership)
5. umount the new volume
6. restart sshd

So even if you have a new instance, the keys will be the same and you will not get prompted.

I assume that you use elastic IP to get the same IP everytime, this to can be put in the user data section.